# Best way to do Audio graph in iOS and Web?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, core-audio

I want to show the audio in graph which is (similar) like the image below
And have to find the low pitches or zero pitches in the audio

I want to do the same in web as well

What is the best way to do it so that I can implement in both web and iOS ??
Is there any API providing this feature in Web or iOS??

If you suggest any tutorial or sample projects it would be great

[image]

Comment: look at this sample example  https://github.com/gyetvan-andras/cocoa-waveform, https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SpeakHere/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Maybe at: http://theamazingaudioengine.com

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can use EZAudio : https://github.com/syedhali/EZAudio.